# storyboard bug with UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

This may be me being stupid, but I'll ask the question anyway (at the risk of being down voted to death).

I have a UITableView in a view controller in story board.  The size is width=213, height=559.  Looks fine in storyboard.

In the ipad simulator (version 6.1) the table has width ~276 and height 559.

I have added no code at all (created a new view controller, dragged in a table, sized it to width213, added a button of width 213 just to have a place marker).  Added a button elsewhere in my app that does a model to the new view controller.

I'm using xcode version 4.6.1

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see this when I try it. I measured the width with a ruler (on the iPad simulator screen), and it calculated out to 212.57, and it was the same width as the button set to a width of 213.

Comment: Hi Rdelmar - Thanks for this.  Are you using the same versions I am?  xcode 4.6.1, ios simulator for ipad version 6.1.  I just upgraded my xcode to 4.6.2, still same results..I'll try to attach an image.

Comment: I'm using version 6.0 of the simulator and 4.6.2 for Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I don't have any tableviews laid out in a storyboard, but since XCode 4.6.~ I have quite a bit of trouble with the "Autolayout" feature. I would try selecting the problematic table view, then under the file inspector, unselect "Use Autolayout" It seems ON by default now, and causes my .xib's and storyboards not to work as I would expect.

Comment: Thanks for this Joe.  I checked the file inspector, 'Use Autolayout' is unselected.

Comment: Sorry that did not help, I have always used the programatic approach to table views. I like the way it looks when I try to use them in a Storyboard, it just never seems to pan out, so I go back to the tried and true.

Comment: The work around is to turn off autosizing in the size inspector, but this doesn't explain why it's happening in the first place.  When I create a new project from scratch, I don't have this problem...it must be some kind of setting.  I'll keep looking...